# Array.sort working differently in chrome and firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I'm trying to sort an array that contains objects, based on the field[marks] in the object. The array is getting sorted differently in Firefox and chrome. In Chrome and IE9 the sixteenth item gets shifted to the top of the array for no reason. Since all the marks are 0 I assumed no sorting will take place. No sorting happens in Firefox but that's not the case with chrome and IE. Please find the code below I have used. Any advice to why this happens would be much appreciated

```
var arr = [
{"userid":"1","name":"USER_1","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"2","name":"USER_2","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"3","name":"USER_3","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"4","name":"USER_4","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"5","name":"USER_5","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"6","name":"USER_6 ","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"7","name":"USER_7","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"8","name":"USER_8","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"9","name":"USER_9","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"10","name":"USER_10","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"11","name":"USER_11","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"12","name":"USER_12","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"13","name":"USER_13","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"14","name":"USER_14","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"15","name":"USER_15","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"16","name":"USER_6","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"17","name":"USER_17","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"18","name":"USER_8","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"19","name":"USER_19","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"20","name":"USER_20","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"21","name":"USER_21","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"22","name":"USER_22","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"23","name":"USER_23","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"24","name":"USER_24","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"25","name":"USER_25","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"26","name":"USER_26","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"27","name":"USER_27","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"28","name":"USER_28","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"29","name":"USER_29","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"30","name":"USER_30","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"31","name":"USER_31","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"32","name":"USER_32","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"},
{"userid":"33","name":"USER_33","subjectid":"123","marks":"0"}
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));

arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return b['marks'] - a['marks'];
});

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i].position = i + 1;
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));​
```

Comment: You could check if the array is sorted before sorting it. [From specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11): *The sort is not necessarily stable (that is, elements that compare equal do not necessarily remain in their original order).*

Comment: Consider using a secondary field for the sort when marks compares equal.